# Conversion of Multi-class dataset to Multi-Label dataset using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have **multi-class** dataset with 3 classes C1,C2 and C3
and some corresponding values as shown in below table

| Class | Value |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | V11 |
| C1 | V12 |
| C2 | V21 |
| C2 | V22 |
| C2 | V23 |
| C3 | V31 |

and we want it to convert it to **multi-label** data set by using all possible **combinations** as shown below

| Value | C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| V11V21 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| V11V22 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| V11V23 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| V11V31 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| V11V21V31 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| V12V21 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| .... | . | . | . |

We are combining the values of different categories and in categoryColumns, we add a 1 if that class is present else we add 0.

Note: Vij is a string so V11V21 is also a string
For example: V11 = 'Hello' V21 = 'Friend' then V11V21 = 'HelloFriend'

Note: I have imported multi-class dataset using pandas in python from a csv file, and it its shape is (n, 2). So solution in Pandas will be a plus, but Its not a necessary, you can give solution using any DS.

Note: This is not an ML problem, it is only a data-conversion problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where: [image]

Getting all the combinations:

```
import itertools
combinations=[]
for number in range(2,len(V)+1):#Combinations except 1 & 0.
    combinations.append([list(a) for a in itertools.combinations(V,number)])
```

One hot encoding classes:

```
Dict={"C1":np.array([1,0,0]),"C2":np.array([0,1,0]),"C3":np.array([0,0,1])}
DF["Class"]=DF["Class"].apply(lambda x :Dict[x])
```

Creating a dict of val_class pairs :

```
Val_class_dict={}
for val in DF.Value.drop_duplicates():
    x=np.sum(DF[DF["Value"]==val].Class.values,axis=0)#Summing them up if there are more than 1 value for each.
    Val_class_dict[val]=x
```

[image]

```
class_vals=[]
val_strs=[]
for a in combinations:
    for b in a:
        zeros=np.array([0,0,0])
        Str=""
        for c in b:
            Str+=str(c)
            zeros+=Val_class_dict[c]
        class_vals.append(zeros)
        val_strs.append(Str)

pd.DataFrame({"Value":val_strs,"C1":np.array(class_vals)[:,0],"C2":np.array(class_vals)[:,1],"C3":np.array(class_vals)[:,2]})
```

[image]

**For Ram-Memory problem, saving per creation:**

```
import csv
import itertools
with open('store.csv', mode='w') as file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    for number in range(2,len(V)+1):
        for a in [list(a) for a in itertools.combinations(V,number)]:
            zeros=np.array([0,0,0])
            Str=""
            for b in a:
                Str+=str(b)
                zeros+=Val_class_dict[b]
            file_writer.writerow((Str,zeros))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Hakan Akgün , Thanks for your answer. It helps me to solve the problem partially, as   in step **Getting all the combinations:** while I am using 35 classes, I am getting out of memory issue. my number of class can reach upto 100 but using only 35 is causing the trouble.

Could you please help me to find the solution where I cannot get memory issue.

I am using system with 16GB RAM.

Comment: You can solve this problem by writing into a file per creation. I'm editing and showing it hope this solves the problem.

Comment: It runs perfectly for few minutes at start But `itertools.combinations(V,number)` is taking too much memory and going out of memory when I passes an array V of size 1068 and crashes.

can we find the combinations in an efficient way as I see its complexity is O(r (n choose r))

Comment: Hmm, this basically happens because V of size 1068 towards its last combinations needs to store 1068*1067 element. What you can do is writing your itertools.combinations into another file and get all the combinations from there per row. Try that if you can't do I can edit the answer.